# Username and Password for Apache Bloodhound

Tags: apache-bloodhound

Installed and configured the apache bloodhound. But unable to login. Not sure what is the default admin username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `python bloodhound_setup.py` while following the [Installation Steps](https://issues.apache.org/bloodhound/wiki/BloodhoundInstall#Installation) you should be prompted to enter a username and password. You can also pass `--admin-user` and `--admin-pass` as options to `python bloodhound_setup.py`. See `python bloodhound_setup.py --help` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Info: 
Default, bloodhound user credentials are stored in digest file, 
**/home/bloodhound/apache-bloodhound-0.8/installer/bloodhound/environments/main/bloodhound.htdigest**

***To Reset Password or To Create User for Apache Bloodhound:***

**Step 1:**
Reset password (or) create new user-id and password:

```
htdigest <digest-file-path> <user-id> <domain>
```

(use htdigest -c option, to create new digest file)
For example:

```
htdigest /home/bloodhound/apache-bloodhound-0.8/installer/bloodhound/environments/main/bloodhound.htdigest bloodhound bloodhound
```

Provide password at prompt:xxxxx

**Step 2:**
Provide admin previleges to the new user:

```
trac-admin <environment-path> permission add TRAC_ADMIN <user-name>
```

For example, to give admin previleges to bloodhound:

```
trac-admin /home/bloodhound/apache-bloodhound-0.8/installer/bloodhound/environments/main permission add TRAC_ADMIN bloodhound
```

**Step 3:**
Trac-Admin user can create other application users in web interface.